# Android - How to get response from a MySQL Database using PHP?

Tags: php, android, mysql, json, android-asynctask

So hello all,

I have a problem getting a response from my php file I created. I'm using AsyncTask to send a request with a SELECT statement which then get's passed throught to MySQL Database localy. I wanted to get the response back to Android as a JSON-String but What I get in Android is just an empty string. If I try the PHP file in browser I'm getting a correct output.

Here are my code Samples:

My AsyncTask class:

```
public class DBHelperAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    private static final String SHARED_PREFERENCE = SharedPreferencesEnum.SHARED_PREFERENCE.getText();
    SharedPreferences prefs;
    final protected Activity currentActivity;
    final protected URL link;
    final protected String fileName;
    private ProgressDialog dialog;

    public DBHelperAsyncTask(Activity currentActivity, URL link, String fileName) throws MalformedURLException
    {
        this.currentActivity = currentActivity;
        this.fileName = fileName;
        this.link = new URL(String.format("http://{0}/{1}", link, fileName));
    }

    public DBHelperAsyncTask(Activity currentActivity, URL link) throws MalformedURLException
    {
        this.currentActivity = currentActivity;
        this.fileName = "uebergabe.php";
        this.link = new URL(String.format("http://{0}/{1}", link, fileName));
    }

    public DBHelperAsyncTask(Activity currentActivity) throws MalformedURLException
    {
        prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(currentActivity);
        this.currentActivity = currentActivity;
        this.fileName = "uebergabe.php";
        this.link = new URL(String.format("http://%s/%s", prefs.getString(SharedPreferencesEnum.HOST.getText(), "127.0.0.1"), prefs.getString(SharedPreferencesEnum.PFAD.getText(), fileName)));
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(currentActivity);
        builder.setTitle(link.toString());
        Dialog dialog = builder.create();
        dialog.show();


    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        dialog = new ProgressDialog(currentActivity);
        dialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        dialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
        dialog.show();
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) link.openConnection();
            connection.setDoOutput(true);

            OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());

            if (params.length > 1) return null;
            else
            {
                String data = URLEncoder.encode("Url", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(params[0], "UTF-8");
                writer.write(data);
                writer.flush();
                writer.close();
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
                StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
                String line = null;
                while((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
                {
                    builder.append(line);
                    break;
                }
                reader.close();
                return builder.toString().trim();
            }

            //Aufruf bei Verbindungsunterbrechung
        } catch (Exception e) {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(currentActivity);
            builder.setTitle("Verbindungsfehler");
            builder.setMessage("Die Verbindung mit dem Server hat fehlergeschlagen");
            builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });


            Dialog dialog = builder.create();
            dialog.show();
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        if(dialog.isShowing()) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    }

    //Konventiert ein json String zum ContentValues
    public ContentValues jsonToContentValues(String jsonString) {
        ContentValues output = new ContentValues();
        JSONObject parser = new JSONObject();
        try {
            if (jsonString == null) throw new JSONException(null);
            parser = new JSONObject(jsonString);
            Iterator<String> iterator = parser.keys();
            JSONArray array = parser.names();
            while (iterator.hasNext()) output.put(iterator.next(), array.getString(output.size()));
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(currentActivity);
            builder.setTitle("Daten-Konvertierungsfehler");
            builder.setMessage("Die Daten konnten nicht richtig gelesen werden\n" + jsonString);
            builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });


            Dialog dialog = builder.create();
            dialog.show();
            return null;
        } finally {
            return output;
        }
    }

}
```

My MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    private static final String SHARED_PREFERENCE = SharedPreferencesEnum.SHARED_PREFERENCE.getText();
    ContentValues result = null;
    private EditText benutzerEditText;
    private EditText passwortEditText;
    private TextView anmeldenTextView;
    DBHelperAsyncTask asyncTask;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREFERENCE, MODE_PRIVATE);

        String benutzer = prefs.getString(SharedPreferencesEnum.BENUTZER.getText(), null);
        if(benutzer == null) {
            setContentView(R.layout.login_maske);
            benutzerEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.benutzerNameEditText);
            passwortEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.benutzerPasswortEditText);
        }
        else
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        Intent intent = null;
        switch(item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.settings_scan:
                intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET);
                intent.setClassName(this, PreferencesActivity.class.getName());
                break;
            case R.id.settings:
                intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET);
                intent.setClassName(this, SettingsActivity.class.getName());
                break;
        }
        startActivity(intent);
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
    public void onAnmeldenClick(View view) throws MalformedURLException, InterruptedException, ExecutionException
    {
        asyncTask = new DBHelperAsyncTask(this);
        String sql = String.format("SELECT IDBenutzer, Passwort FROM benutzer where Benutzername = '{0}'", benutzerEditText.getText().toString());
        result = asyncTask.jsonToContentValues(asyncTask.execute(sql).get());

        anmeldenTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.anmeldenTextView);
        anmeldenTextView.setText(result.toString());
        /*
        String passwort = result.getAsString("Passwort");
        if(passwortEditText.getText().toString() == passwort)
        {
            SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREFERENCE, MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
            editor.putInt(SharedPreferencesEnum.BENUTZER_ID.getText(), result.getAsInteger("IDBenutzer"));
            editor.putString(SharedPreferencesEnum.BENUTZER.getText(), result.getAsString("Benutzer"));
        }*/
    }


    public void onPruefenClick(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
        startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == 0) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

                String contents = data.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT");
                AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this).create();
                dialog.setTitle("Barcode");
                dialog.setMessage(contents);
                dialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEUTRAL, "OK",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                dialog.dismiss();
                            }
                        });
                dialog.show();
                // Handle successful scan

            }
        }
    }


    public void onAbmeldenClick(View view)
    {
        SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREFERENCE, MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        editor.remove(SharedPreferencesEnum.BENUTZER.getText());
        editor.remove(SharedPreferencesEnum.BENUTZER_ID.getText());
        editor.commit();
        restartActivity(this);
    }

    private void restartActivity(Activity restartActivity)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setClass(restartActivity, restartActivity.getClass());
        restartActivity.startActivity(intent);
        restartActivity.finish();
    }
}
```

And the PHP file:

```
    <?php

    $link = "localhost";
    $user = "root";
    $password = "";
    $dbname = "ProjektZ";

    $conn = mysqli_connect($link,$user,$password,$dbname);

    if ($conn->connect_error) {
                #Script verlassen
                die("Connection failed");
            } 
            $sql = $_POST['Url']; #sql-anfrage erstellen
            $myArray = array();
            if ($result = $conn->query($sql)) #sql-anfrage ausführen und in Variable speichern
            if(is_object($result))
            {
                while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQL_ASSOC)) $myArray[] = $row;
                header('Content-type: application/json');
                echo json_encode($myArray);     
            }
            mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

Everywhere I read it states that echo json_encode($myArray) should be correct way to pass response back to the app.

Comment: IMO you shouldn't do user verification on the client (Android) side. You should do that on server (PHP) side. And please hash the passwords. It seems as if you were storing them in plain text. The whole login process here looks very vulnerable to me.

Comment: It's basic approach just to test if it functions at all. Other things like Encrypiton will follow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should consider using a [REST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) approach for getting data from your database. It'll be much more easier to the Android application and much more safe (SQL injections are a risk in your code).
You can use a CMS like [Symfony](https://symfony.com/) (or any ohter CMS that you like) to help you build that server side.

Comment: Does this collide with e.g. XAMPP or such? And more important, is this much diffrent than working simply with Apache and HTTP-Requests?

Comment: I see you're already using a XAMP environment, so it's a simple step. No, it's not that different, it's even simpler, safer and faster than doing all of these by hand.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions where to start if would be going to change to REST. Are there any other installations than XAMPP on server needed to use REST?

Comment: You can read this tutorial : http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSRestBundle/index.html. And XAMP is just what you need.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I will check it out.

Comment: BTW I solved the problem with this code myself. The String.format was wrong, so I was sending wrong SQL-Statement in the first place.